# Moving charge thought experiment paradox

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Let’s say you have a moving charge, relative to a stationary observer. They measure that it has an electric field $E$ and a magnetic field $B$. Because the observer is stationary, they experience no magnetic force only the electric force. However, because that charge is moving, relative to my stationary observer there is a changing magnetic field around that charge causing a curl in the electric field. This means that, even though the observer is not moving, it is indirectly experiencing a different force compared to when the charge is not moving (experiencing a non-conservative force). Is this correct? And does that mean that moving charge affects things differently even if the observer has zero velocity (i.e. experiences no magnetic force)?

Also let’s now look at the frame of reference of the moving charge. In its frame of reference there is a static electric field and no magnetic field, so the observer must experience a *conservative* force? Why is there a contradiction between frames as each frame experiences different forces by only an electric force?

Comment: Are you aware of the relationship between electricity and magnetism in special relativity?

Comment: Force is not invariant under boost transformations, so there is no reason to expect different observers to see the same force being exerted on a charge.